# Remove new tab with most visited websites in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When I open a new tab in Firefox, my most visited sites appear in a grid. How do I get rid of this? Not that I'm trying to hide anything :). It's just that having Facebook keep popping up all the time. It is distracting me from my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable or disable the Google new tab page

1. Click the Toolbar's wrench icon.

   [image: wrench]
2. On the Search tab, select (or deselect) the 'Enable the Google new tab page' checkbox.
3. Click Save.

[Google Help Article With Video](http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115561)

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: The question is for Firefox, not for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 11):

[As of Firefox 13](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/13.0/releasenotes/), this new tab page has become a built-in feature.

To disable it, you can click the grid icon on the top right corner of the page:

[image: Screenshot of icon]

Alternatively, you can navigate to `about:config`, search for `browser.newtabpage.enabled` and double click it to set it to `false` (or set the `browser.newtab.url` to `about:blank` or whatever). This is the setting the grid icon toggles.

Of course, if you have an extension such as Google Toolbar or New Tab King providing the page as suggested in the other answers, this method won't work. **This method is only to disable the built-in most visited new tab page in Firefox 13 and newer.**

Comment: Thank god. That is absolutely the most bletcherous "feature" I've been subjected to as an "upgrade" in ages.

Comment: @dmckee As long as it's possible to disable, it's all good :) It's those 'features' that can't be disabled/reverted that are a pain...

Comment: "browser.newtab.url" = "about:blank" also helps Firefox feel faster, at least on underpowered machines.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't normal behavior. You should be getting a blank page.

It's most probably an add-on that you have installed, maybe [New Tab King](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10828).

Find the add-on and disable it to get rid of this behavior.

Comment: i'm using google toolbar yes, maybe it's an option on that, i'll have a look...

Answer (score 3):

this is the answer. It's the "enable the google new tab page" in the google toolbar options

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is another way but this should work:

```
Tools->Addons, disable "Google Toolbar for Firefox"
```

Comment: ahh probably google toolbar...i don't want to disable that one though

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to remove the New Tab King extension from Firefox:

1. Click on the Firefox menu and select "Add-ons"
2. Click on "Extensions", then find New Tab King in the list and click on "Remove"

You will be sent to a page asking you why you are removing the extension. Feel free to ignore it.

Comment: Also, you will benefit from installing this add on after you follow the above removal of the King Tab extension.  
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/